# Cannot Cmd+Click on some Android framework member field usages within IntelliJ

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

It seems that, using IntelliJ to browse Android framework code (like android.os.Message) I cannot Cmd+Click on usages of some member fields to navigate to their declaration.  An example is Message.next.  The error message when I try to do so is "Cannot resolve symbol next".

Not sure if it's relevant, but something these fields have in common is `/*package*/` in front of each declaration.  This doesn't happen when I open the same class in Android Studio.

Why is this happening, and is there a way to fix it?  Because I prefer staying in IntelliJ, rather than switching to Android Studio just for Android dev.

Comment: You need to add the Android sources to your project.

Comment: like @Zar said; the source code needed to have been downloaded/in your classpath.  You can go a little further by enabling auto-import of source (& documentation) from Intellij.  This way you can CMD+Click and zip through source code and docs at will